# Pass CoreData into UICalendarView to show decorations and click on date for detail view

Tags: ios, swiftui

**** UPDATED 1/21/23 ****
Got the decorations working on UICALENDARVIEW. Can you guys please help with:

1. How to pass through the CoreData entries to the Calendar to show decorations on only the dates with entries? (currently getting error 'Cannot convert value of type 'FetchedResults' to expected argument type 'ObservedObject'' on the line of

> Coordinator(parent: self, items: items)

2. Allow selection of that date to go to the detail view?

My CoreData Entity is named 'Item'. Ideas? I updated the code I have below:

CALENDARHELPER:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarHelper: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: SleepSort.default.descriptors,
            animation: .default)
        private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    let interval: DateInterval
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
        let calView = UICalendarView()
        calView.delegate = context.coordinator
        calView.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calView.availableDateRange = interval
        calView.fontDesign = .rounded
        let dateSelection = UICalendarSelectionSingleDate(delegate: context.coordinator)
        calView.selectionBehavior = dateSelection
        calView.wantsDateDecorations = true
        return calView
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self, items: _items)
        }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICalendarView, context: Context) {

    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICalendarViewDelegate, UICalendarSelectionSingleDateDelegate {
            var parent: CalendarHelper
            @ObservedObject var items: Item
        
            init(parent: CalendarHelper, items: ObservedObject<Item>) {
                self.parent = parent
                self._items = items
            }
            
            @MainActor
            func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
                let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
                let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(font: font)
                let image = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill", withConfiguration: configuration)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                return .image(image)
            }
            
            func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate,
                               didSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) {
            }
            
            func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate,
                               canSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) -> Bool {
                return true
            }
            
        }
}
```

CALVIEW:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct CalView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Calendar View")
                        .bold()
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .font(.title)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.032, saturation: 0.734, brightness: 0.973))
                        .frame(width: 65, height:20)
                        .shadow(radius: 7)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .overlay {
                            Text("BETA")
                                .font(.system(size:12))
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        }
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        NavigationLink(destination: AddView()) {
                             Text("+")
                         }  .font(.system(size: 30)).fontWeight(.heavy)
                            .frame(width: 33, height: 25)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .padding(.bottom, 7)
                            .background(Color(hue: 0.032, saturation: 0.734, brightness: 0.973))
                            .cornerRadius(38.5)
                            .padding(.trailing, 15)
                    })
                }   .padding(.leading, 20)
                    .padding(.top, 5)

                HStack {
                   CalendarHelper(interval: DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: .distantFuture))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `items` represents all the `Item` entries in Core Data, not just ones for a given day. You'll have to query it to find a given date (using the `DateComponents` is present.

Comment: SwiftUI wrappers only work in SwiftUI views, you can’t use them in a class

Comment: Ok, how would I accomplish this without the class?

Comment: Any ideas? Or is there even a way to display the decorations based on if there is a CoreData entry for that date? And then the ability to use that decoration to NavigationLink to the detail view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but i think i have the solution now:

1. first you should fetch all your Items regardless of the created Dates into an Array, to do that:

   ```
    var allItems:[ItemEntity] = []
    func fetchAllNotes() {
          let request = NSFetchRequest<ItemEntity>(entityName: "ItemEntity")

      do {
          allItems = try dataManager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
          print("Data loaded")
      }catch let error {
          print("Error")
      }

    }
   ```

Then filter 'allItems' array with dateComponents:

```
    @MainActor
        func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
            

            let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(font: font)
            let image = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill", withConfiguration: configuration)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

            let itemsOfDay = model.allItems.filter{ $0.date?.startOfDay == dateComponents.date?.startOfDay}

            if itemsOfDay.count > 0 {
              return .image(image)
            }else{
            return nil
            }
        }   




import Foundation

extension Date {

    var startOfDay: Date {
    
        Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self)
    
    }

}
```

This code will put a star under of a day, when in that day more than one 'Item' exist.

Comment: I'm trying to follow along with above but it's giving me two errors. The first is 'Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable' on the allItems = try.... line. The second is on the line let itemsOfDay = model..... as it's saying it can't find model in scope. Any ideas?